# Animation to make height of a Rectangle to 0 in windows 8 app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In win8 app I am trying small animation to make height of Rectangle 0

Properties like Opacity are working fine, but I am not able to bring animation in height or width.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="NewStory">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources> 

<Rectangle Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Tapped="MyRectangle_OnTapped">

private void MyRectangle_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NewStory.Begin();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you try to change something that influences layout then an animation for this change is called *dependent animation*, and it doesn't work by default. To be able to use it you should set EnableDependentAnimation property to true.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="NewStory">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" EnableDependentAnimation="true" />
</Storyboard>
```